# getting a pop-up area with mouseover from the wordpress admin-bar

Tags: wordpress, popup

I'm in the process of writing a plugin to display some site information to all logged users of a blog.

The easiest way I've found is to attach the info to the the admin-bar. However I'd like to display more information then will easily fit. I'd like to put the data in an overlayed html box that is displayed when the user mouses-over (or clicks) on the title.

In effect I'd like to recreate the effect of the "howdy" item.
Below is the reverent code from my plugin.

```
$args = array(
    'id'    => 'counter',
    'title'  => $visitor_count . ' Unique visitors and ' . $page_views .' Page views',
    'href' => '#',
    'aria-haspopup' => 'true',
    'meta' => array( 'html' => '
    <!-- This should be a pop-up message not a fixed box -->
    <div style="width:300px;height:100px;background-color:white;box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;">
    here be html
    </div>

    ')
);
$wp_admin_bar->add_node( $args );
```

Hopefully this makes some sense to you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK cracked it, but looking at the WP source code. meta['onclick'] is escaped but allows javascript, so that can be used to call a function which shows/hide's the div passed in meta['html'].

i.e. (yes I know it just unhides this, but a function should be easy to add to meta['onclick'], that checks and hide's or unhide's the div)

```
global $wpdb;
global $SH_SWS_data;
$page_views = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ".$SH_SWS_data->tableName);
$visitor_count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ip) FROM ".$SH_SWS_data->tableName);

$args = array(
    'id'    => 'counter',
    'title'  => $visitor_count . ' Unique visitors and ' . $page_views .' Page views',
    'href' => '#',
    'aria-haspopup' => 'true',
    'meta' => array( 'html' => '
    <div id="SH_SWS_message_box" style="visibility:hidden;" width="200px" height="100px" >

    <div id="SH_SWS_Chart">Hi all</div>

    </div>
    ', 
            'onclick' => 'document.getElementById("SH_SWS_message_box").style.visibility="visible";')
);
$wp_admin_bar->add_node( $args );
```